# Correct CSS Menu Hover Function

Tags: css, colors, hover

I have made my nav menu myself, and theres is just one thing I can't seem to figure out ... How Can I make the A tag color white when I'm hovering over the ul id "navitemul"
I tried `#lovedating#navitemul:hover #lovedating a {color:white}` and a few other methods but none seems to be working, could someone just point me in the right direction :) If you wish to see the nav bar in action visit my site: www.curious-howto.com, and you can get a better impression of what I wish to accomplish ...
Thank You

Philippe

```
<li style="width:150px" id="lovedating"><a href="#">Love & Dating</a>
<div id="love&dating" class="belownav">
<div class="ontop">Love & Dating</div>
<div class="navitem"><ul id="navitemul">
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/broken-hearths/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Broken-Hearths.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Broken Hearths</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/dating/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Dating.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Dating</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/dating-humor/">    <img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Dating-Humor.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">General Health</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/flirting/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Flirting.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Flirting</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/kissing/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Kissing.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Kissing</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/physical-relationships/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/Physical-Relationships.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Physical Relationships</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/relationships/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/relationships.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Relationships</span></a></li>
<li class="marright"><a href="http://www.curious-howto.com/love-dating/weddings/"><img class="fl" src="http://www.curious-howto.com/images/2013/04/weddings.jpg" width="63" height="40" /><span class="marleft">Weddings</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#love&dating a:hover{color:#FFF;}
```

Comment: Not quite was I was looking for, I want the Menu Title, which is <a href="#">Love & Dating</a> to stay white while hovering hover the rest of the menu ...

Comment: I thank you for your effort but I don't think we are on the same page ... you code makes all the a link inside #love&dating turn white on hover, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to leave the menu title white while hovering over the rest of the menu ... Right now I hover over menu title and it turns white, but when I hover of the submenu the menu title turn back to its original color of blue, I want it to stay white so that when people are hovering the menu they know that they are still in that category ...

Answer (score 0):

tyr this one

```
ul li#lovedating a:hover { color:green;}
```

Comment: Same thing here :( I want the menu title to stay white while hovering over the rest of the menu, not for all the a tags inside the menu to turn color ... just the title to stay white so people know which category they are viewing ...

Comment: Try below one. I hope it will help. Just assign color according  your require

li#lovedating a { color:white;}

ul#navitemul li a { color:black;}

ul#navitemul li a:hover { color:red;}

Comment: Dam I dunno how to explain this better, I want top menu <li style="width:150px" id="lovedating"><a href="#">Love & Dating</a> to stay color white while hovering over submenu <ul id="navitemul">, here aagin you showing how to turn a tag inside <ul id="navitemul"> to turn red ... not what I'm trying to accomplish, I thank you for you opinion tho

Comment: Sorry i think i m not getting your problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
#lovedating#navitemul:hover #lovedating a {color:white}
```

to

```
#navitemul:hover a {color:white}
```